# Link loses action in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, shopping-cart

I'm creating and removing HTML from inside a div with jQuery (shopping cart, adding/removing items). I need to access the `.click()` event of a link inside this div, but it only works when the page first loads - after that link is removed then re-added it doesn't respond to any jQuery events.

I've tried functions both inside and outside of `$j(document).ready(function() {}`. How can I make events work on this link again after re-creation?

Comment: What do you mean: "after that link is removed then re-added it doesn't respond to any jQuery events." Show your's  code

Comment: There are dozens of SO questions about this. Look into event delegation and the `on` method. The problem is that the elements you've bound to no longer exist, new ones do instead, so the old event handlers are gone.

Comment: Is it possible to post an example to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: You might want to look at JQuery's live() function. And, post some of your code for us to better understand :)

Comment: @NitinSinghal `.live()` is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7. Instead take a look at `.delegate()` which was the preferred method since its conception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.delegate()` instead of `.click()` (which is short-hand for `.bind('click')`):

```
$(<root-element>).delegate('a', function () {...});
```

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the
>   selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root
>   elements.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/*

The `<root-element>` can be the `document` element or if you know an element that is always present that is a descendant of the `document` element it is best to use that element.

Comment: Or in 1.7 you can just use `on(..., function() { });`

Comment: That is true, `$(<root-element>).delegate(<selector>, <event>, <event handler>)` == `$(<root-element>).on(<event>, <selector>, <event handler>)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to either reattach the event every time you overwrite the content of your container div or set handler using `live/delegate/on` depending on the version of jQuery you use.

Second method is in general more elegant, but has drawbacks. In particular you cannot cancel the default action from cascaded even attached to the container.

Answer (score 1):

The `.click()` event only works for elements that are present with the function is called.  You need to look into using either [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attach listeners to elements that are dynamically created after `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.detach()` instead of `.remove()`, that will keep the events. Alternatively use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).